# Publishing Consumer Fraud

Tags: publications, ethics

I'm in the awkward position where I have been giving a data set from a company **strongly** indicating that consumer fraud occurs in a certain business sector (insurance). The data permits me to identify the corporations conducting the fraud.

I come from a completely different scientific background than consumer law. Therefore, my questions regarding this matter:

- Is an academic peer-reviewed journal even a suitable channel for this kind uncovering?
- If published in an academic journal, will I be able to name the companies conducting the fraud?
- What journals might be suitable for this?
- Do any similar cases come to mind which I could study?

Thanks

Comment: If you are in the US you should (and really must) speak with your local IRB before going any further.

Comment: Your university (assuming you work at one) surely has a legal office. I would suggest to pay them a visit.

Comment: Isn't engaging in fraud practically part of being an insurance company?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question rather than an academic one, and A) a lawyer reading your question won't answer it because they won't want the answer to be construed as legal advice and B) a non-lawyer is likely to give you bad legal advice.

Comment: I think you could potentially keep this question on-topic if you rephrase it to be able how to address these issues as an academic, in which case you would get answers like the ones in the comments (i.e., directing you to legal resources that likely exist at your institution that could help you with this). Any other type of answer you get here I'd strongly suggest you ignore.

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects to this, one in your domain and the other outside it.

If you have a data set, assuming it is valid and accurate, you can analyze it an publish your findings. That is just science. Like any other study, your methodology is important and your conclusions must follow from the data.

But alleging fraud is a legal matter that should only be left to lawyers, courts, etc. It is not your proper role, even though your findings may *be interpreted* to imply fraud.

If you name companies at all, stick to facts, not allegations. Don't use legal terms, especially legally loaded terms that might lead to a charge of slander, whether justified or not. The company lawyers are better than any you could afford.

Facts, however, are facts, and can be reported and analyzed. Do that, but leave the legal implications to those better placed to follow up on them.

---

Let me try to be more clear. First, analyzing data seems to me to have no legal issues.

However, I warn the OP not to make statements that can be interpreted as allegations of misbehavior on the part of others. They may have an "action at law" against you if you do that and it will be expensive to defend your actions even if you are correct.

Let others form the conclusions from your research rather than making or implying accusations.

If legal authorities have some evidence of fraud they can act on it. That can bring the courts to bear, but the regulatory authorities have to act first. That would, perhaps, be a *criminal* matter and it would be out of your hands altogether. (Note that some improper actions handled by authorities are also civil, resulting in fines, rather than criminal. But still it is up to them to make the allegations and follow it up.)

If you make allegations and are sued, on the other hand, it is a *civil* matter and the courts are only involved in the adjudication of the dispute between the parties. But being sued is not without cost, even if, again, you are correct. If you allege publicly that a large company has committed fraud you may well be sued and the company probably has a highly qualified legal team that will do what it can to shut you up. If you are Jeff Bezos you can fight such claims since you can afford the best lawyers yourself. Otherwise it is a financial life wrecker.

Comment: Careful!!  Truth is (at least in principle) an absolute defense against libel claims in the United States, but the same is not true in all countries. **Speak to a lawyer first.**

Comment: @JeffE, but it doesn't stop you from being sued and you have to defend, requiring your own lawyer. The civil law is often used for intimidation rather than justice. So, "in principle but not necessarily in practice".

Comment: You're right, of course. But the conclusion is the same: "Merely" reporting and analyzing facts can still lead to serious legal difficulty. So even in the US, your advice "Do that" is a bit careless.

Comment: @JeffE, that depends of course on what you say.

Comment: "A person is considered innocent until proven broke"... Does truth & justice or the most expensive lawyer prevail?

Comment: Can courts in the US really "allege fraud"? Your answer reads like "Hope some lawyer-scientist will stumble upon your publication and decide to take things to court." Is this actually what you're trying to say?

Comment: @sgf, I don't understand. Courts aren't involved except to adjudicate disputes between individuals. If I say you have committed fraud, you can sue me. I have to respond to that suit to avoid summary judgement against me. I dare not do that without a competent attorney. But if you are a rich company or individual you can afford the best representation and I cannot. A "stumbler" has no "standing" to sue. It has to be you, the person accused, not a random person. (US perspective).

Comment: @Buffy "[A]lleging fraud is a legal matter that should only be left to lawyers, courts, etc" - This read to me as if courts could allege fraud.

Comment: @Buffy But the more important point is that you seem to be considering two alternatives: Publicly denouncing company X as fraudulent, or just publishing the facts. There seems to me to be an obvious third alternative: Very carefully taking the necessary legal steps to stop the fraud. This will of course also involve a lawyer, but it seems to me that this is OP's proper role as a citizen (if, indeed, they are.)

Comment: @sgf. I don't mention "courts". This is civil, not criminal law. You aren't "arrested" by authorities. But you can be ordered to appear in court where the civil dispute is handled. Courts don't initiate anything. Only the "aggrieved" party can do that.

Comment: The OP could inform the "police" or other authorities that fraud has occurred. They might open an investigation, but the OP wouldn't be part of it. The OP can't sue the "perpetrators" unless the OP has been defrauded personally. This is called _standing_. I can only sue on for damages done to _me_ not to others. As you say, there may be other alternatives than the ones I suggest. My intent was only to warn the OP away from anything that makes any allegations whatever because of the personal risk it entails.

Comment: @Buffy The so-called police?

Comment: @sgf. not every authority is necessarily called "police". There are regulatory authorities and such. But you can only make a complaint. Then it is up to them to follow up or not.

Comment: Fraud can be criminal or civil. One can easily run afoul of criminal laws and end up in prison by lying to customers. Libel can be civil or criminal too, though criminal libel is far more rare.

Comment: @ASimpleAlgorithm, I'm speaking about "alleging" fraud, potentially slander/libel. Not the fraud itself.

Comment: @ASimpleAlgorithm, and others. According to the UN charter, defamation (slander, libel) should never be a criminal matter. Some countries have been called on this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defamation.

Comment: @Buffy not strictly true.  you can allege fraud against the government and sue on the government's behalf.

Comment: @emory, please be more precise here. The crime would be fraud, not slander. Alleging a fraud isn't what is being called a "crime" anywhere here. Things are being conflated that are not the same. Using "fraud" and "allegation" in the same sentence has become too confusing in this comment sequence. Again, defamation is  properly  a civil matter. Your comment doesn't speak to that at all.

Comment: @Buffy I mean if your data suggests that a 3rd party is defrauding the government (but not you personally) then in the US (and many other countries) you can file a 'qui tam' lawsuit and if you prevail be entitled to a fraction of damages.  1. You do not have to be personally damaged to have standing (though it helps).  2. There can be an upside as well as a downside to making the allegations.